# Searching for jQuery thumbnail gallery with auto-resize

Tags: jquery, resize, gallery, thumbnails, image-resizing

I need a thumbnail gallery, where I would put the image link only once, original size image. And then the gallery would automaticaly resize the thumbnail and put it the thumbnail div.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what have you tried? There are 100's of image sliders with thumbnail support

Comment: I still didn't find none with the funcionality I need. I'm thinking of using Resize Plugin - Nailthumb (here's the [link](http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php) ) and then clone the element. Example: Put an original image and resize it to the field dimensions, then copy the image and paste it in thumbnail div and resize once again to Thumbnail size. Still investigating...

I need this funcionality, because I'm creating a template's and to paste the same images several times is anoying and unproffesional.

Comment: look at cycle.js or cycle2.js

Comment: to complicated for me, I'm a begginer in jQuery and scripting in general.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [this slider/gallery](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html)

Comment: It's nice, but still, in this slider you have to paste the images twice.